# difference between Json.Unmarshal() and gin.BindJson()

Tags: go, go-gin

hi i'm new to gin framework and golang and i was wondering what's the difference between Json.Unmarshal() and gin.BindJson()

in the tutorial he's building a video service which has two methods, save and findall

```
func (vc *videoControllerStruct) Save(ctx *gin.Context) entity.Video {
    video := entity.Video{}
    ctx.ShouldBind(&video) // ctx.BindJson(&video)
    vc.services.Save(video)
    return video
```

as you can see he used ctx.BindJson first and then changed it to ShouldBind (idk why)
is there a way to re-write this code with json.unmarshal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main differences between json.Unmarshal and gin.BindJson are:

- json.Unmarshal operates on raw JSON data, while gin.BindJson binds
  from a request body to a struct.
- json.Unmarshal requires manually getting the JSON data ([]byte),
  while gin.BindJson handles getting JSON data from request
  transparently.
- gin.BindJson can do extra validation and binding, while
  json.Unmarshal just unmarshals raw JSON.

To use json.Unmarshal with gin, you would have to do something like:

```golang
func (vc *videoController) Save(ctx *gin.Context) {

  // Get JSON data 
  var jsonData []byte
  if ctx.Request.Body != nil {
    jsonData, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(ctx.Request.Body)
  }

  // Declare video struct
  var video entity.Video

  // Unmarshal into struct
  err := json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &video)
  if err != nil {
    // handle error
  }

  // Save video 
  vc.services.Save(video)

  // Return saved video
  return video

}
```

Comment: You’re welcome ;) buchana

Answer (score 3):

`ShouldBind` looks like this:

```
func (c *Context) ShouldBind(obj any) error {
    b := binding.Default(c.Request.Method, c.ContentType())
    return c.ShouldBindWith(obj, b)
}
```

It basically checks for the request method and content type, and based on that, it resolves the binding. So, the incoming content can be something else than JSON.

`BindJson` is just an alias for `MustBindWith(obj, binding.JSON)` that strictly tries to unmarshal the request body to JSON. Passing any other content will produce a 400 HTTP status.

You could also use `json.Unmarshal`, but you'd have to explicitly access the request body in a Gin context.